# bash: etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

```
i159@i159-desktop:~$ psql -U geouser -W -d deodb
Password for user geouser: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "geouser"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "geouser"
```

After this I checked in `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf`.

When am executing the above command am getting this error:

```
bash: etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't start without this file - so pg_hba.conf should exist on your server.

This file is usually in data directory - you can try

```
sudo su postgres
psql postgres -c "show hba_file"
```